# Discriminated unions and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, f#, discriminated-union

I'm looking to create a scene-graph for my F# project somthing like:

```
root
->player_bob
-->torch
->enemy_1
-->extravagant_hat
-->enemies_cat_jess 
--->fleas
--->fur_ball
->loot
```

etc,etc.

Each item needs to hold a collection of game objects to represent it's children.

e.g enemy1's list contains a cat and a hat and the cats list contains fleas and a fur ball

So I plan to make them all inherit from a class that contains a collection that describes that objects children.

**Now to my question:**
Should I down-cast child objects to GameObject's and store them in a list of the "GameObject" base class
OR create a discriminating union e.g

```
type SceneObject = 
        |Character of Character //e.g player, enemy, cat
        |Item of Item //e.g hat, torch, furball
```

And store objects as a list of "SceneObjects" to avoid any problems/overheads with up-casting them, etc. As well as allowing me to describe special cases where the object isn't rendered and/or not used in collision detection e.g: sound emitters, trap triggers, etc.

The discriminated union + inheritance combo is my initial thought; though, as I'm new to FP, I thought it wise to ask the pro's for the best, functional, way of approaching this.

Thanks,

JD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the discriminated union *recursively*.

```
type SceneObject = 
    | Character of <characterData> * (SceneObject list) 
    | Item      of <itemData>      * (SceneObject list)
```

And use it like this

```
let root = [Character("Bob", [Item("Torch", []); ...]); ...]
```

Comment: Brilliant! This eliminates the need for the inheritance :¬)
Thanks Dario, half my problem with learning FP is pulling my head out of OO land.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to what Dario suggest is to declare a separate type for actual objects in the game (such as items and characters) and wrap it in another object that adds a list of child objects. This would look like this:

```
type SceneObject =
  | Character of <characterData>
  | Item of <itemData>

type ObjectWithChildren = 
  { Object : SceneObject
    Children : ObjectWithChildren list }
```

Both of the options are correct functional design, but I would prefer this version, because it makes certain kinds of processing easier. For example, if you wanted to traverse all objects in the game tree, you can write something like:

```
let rec traverse tree = 
  // Do something with tree.Object
  for child in tree.Children do traverse child
```

In this version, you don't need to pattern match on `SceneObject` at all, so you don't need to include all the cases (such as `Item` and `Character`).

Comment: Interesting. This is how I've modelled the Character class and its state machine.
A character record to hold all the raw data (location, health, etc) (CharacterRecord).


A mailbox processor as the state machine (CharacterStateMachine).

And then wrapped the two up in the "Character" record that holds {state:CharacterStateMachine; data:CharacterRecord}.

Then used members to make some user-friendly getters and setters...

So this solution fits well with my current model. 

I'll have to give both of these a try,

Many thanks.